# function which iterates over numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have written a simple function which iterates over a numpy array with some fixed indices.

```
def compute_V(i,j,nA, nB,V):
    Vijkl = np.zeros((i,j,nA,nB))
    for k in range(nA):
        for l in range(nB):
            Vijkl[i,j,k,l] = V[i,j,k,l] + 3

    return Vijkl
```

I am getting the following error back:
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

What am I doing wrong?

The matrix V has a shape: (1, 2, 1, 2) and looks:

```
[[[[-0.00009 -0.00001]]

  [[-0.00001 -0.00001]]]] 

i = 0, j = 0, nA = 1, nB = 2
```

Looks the loop goes over one iteration:

```
i,j,k,l,V:  0 0 0 0 -9.39073120245e-05
```

then throws the error.

Comment: IndexError means that you are trying to get an element that doesn't exist in the List. For example imagine if your trying to get the forth element of a list, even though the list only has three elements.

Comment: What's the shape of V? Could be that it's a mismatch with nA or nB?

Comment: V is (1, 2, 1, 2), nA = 1, nB =2

Comment: Not really related to your question, but if all you do is to fill 3 in some of the elements there are much more elegant ways to do so.

Comment: @anishtain4 It just an example for more complicated task.

Comment: The code you have posted will always throw an error the first time through the i,j loops, because i and j will always be 1 larger than the max bound for those dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape of Vijkl is (i, j, nA, nB), so the maximum limits for each dimension are (i-1, j-1, nA-1, nB-1). You are exceeding the maximum range of the first two dimensions.